# Windows 10 Force Application to use GPU

Tags: windows-10, gpu

Running Windows 10 21H2. Trying to force textinputhost.exe to always use integrated GPU so it doesn't use my dGPU and eat battery life. Anyone know why and how to fix?

I've set the GPU affinity  (check the screenshot), but somehow the setting is being ignored and it's still using my dGPU

[image]

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Have you researched GPU affinity?

Comment: @music2myear sorry, I assumed the screenshot would explain things, but I've already set the GPU affinity and it's not taking effect, that's my problem

Answer (score -1):

This guide explains how to set GPU affinity on Windows 10:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103965-set-preferred-gpu-apps-windows-10-a.html

As for TextInputHost.exe ? You would have to add it as a desktop app and browse for the exe. Using the Task manager right click on textinputhost and then Open File Location. Even if you set GPU affinity now, you may have to re-set it to point to a new package location after a windows update.

For me background apps chew up battery faster. Settings/Privacy/Background Apps. I turn everything off except for security and the printer app.

Comment: I already did that, the problem is that they aren't being enforced.

Comment: Use Sysinternal ProcExplorer and find TextInputHost.exe. You'll see that it is a process under svchost.exe. TextInputHost is not itself a GUI application.  However it launches a GUI app  -ServerName:InputApp.App......hashedname...mca